# ASP.NET Deserialize Json object with single and array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I am very new to json, please help me out! Suppose I have the following json object

```
{
    "Table": "",
    "Id": "",
    "Column": [
        {
            "ColumnText": "",
            "ColumnSqlName": ""
        },
        {
            "ColumnText": "",
            "ColumnSqlName": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to use asp.net to deserialize the above json, what is the best way to do this? Thanks!!!

Comment: mark at least one solution as accepted, if issue resolved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Public Class JsonObj
    Private _Table As String
    Public Property Table() As String
        Get
            Return _Table
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Table = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Id As String
    Public Property Id() As String
        Get
            Return _Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Column As JsonSetting()
    Public Property Column() As JsonSetting()
        Get
            Return _Column
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As JsonSetting())
            _Column = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class JsonSetting
    Private _ColumnText As String
    Public Property ColumnText() As String
        Get
            Return _ColumnText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _ColumnText = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ColumnSqlName As String
    Public Property ColumnSqlName() As String
        Get
            Return _ColumnSqlName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _ColumnSqlName = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim o As New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim instance As JsonObj = o.Deserialize(Of JsonObj)(json_str)
```

Thanks for all of your reply, but the above code may work great.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use the [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library to serialize and deserialize the objects into json

For Example: it deserialize the json object into C# object...

```
string json = @"{
  ""Name"": ""Apple"",
  ""Expiry"": new Date(1230422400000),
  ""Price"": 3.99,
  ""Sizes"": [
    ""Small"",
    ""Medium"",
    ""Large""
  ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

string name = (string)o["Name"];
// Apple

JArray sizes = (JArray)o["Sizes"];

string smallest = (string)sizes[0];
// Small
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) has a simple example for you to follow. If it is a service, it may be easier to simply consume it using WCF though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in class `JavaScriptSerializer` this. `MyClass` is a class matching the json structure

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
MyClass instance = serializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(myJson);
```