# Deserialize an array out of JSON using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm trying to get the "result" array out of this JSON string, but can't figure out the best way to do it:

```
{"error": null, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "result": ["1", "0", "100.00", "0", "None", "GBP", "", "", "", "", "603628-200007313", "", "", "GBP", ""]}
```

Ideally I need the 3 pairs before it too, plus the array so I can do something with it.

If anyone can help I'd appreciate it.  I've been trying to use both JSON.Net and the built in Serialization class but all of the examples I've found seem to be about grabbing name-value pairs into an object.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Actually, as is so often the way, I've figured it out - I'll post my solution when I'm allowed, but it's from this StackOverflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10914180/130408

Answer (score 0):

I use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer class.

You can then deserialze to a given class or to an anonymous object.

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
...
Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim oJsObject As JsObject = json.Deserialize(Of JsObject )(jsonstring)
```